# Armature Bones Don't update when switching between Pose position and Reset position

Tags: armature

Two of my rig bones are getting stuck when switching between the Pose position and Reset position
[image: Reset position]
[image: Pose position]

Comment: hello, it is not clear, do you mean that you can't move the bone in Pose mode? maybe share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I can move the bone but when switching to pose mode the bone gets stuck
I don't want to share my file because I have an entire animation in it

Comment: share the armature only, make a file as simple as possible  ;)

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/1278f02fe98f4e69947833842d2a06e0

Comment: It's the bone constraint on the *DEF-Robe.M* bone that causes the glitch. I'm not sure if there is something wrong (cyclic dependency?) or it's a bug in Blender because if you click 2x on the Pose Position button or select another bone then it updates and the bone moves into position.

Comment: Do you think there's a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I'm not a rigging expert and not sure what you're doing with all these constraints. Can you give more details about what you're want to do (probably rig the robe) and how it should work? Maybe someone else knows the solution.

Comment: It's working (mostly) as intended, the robes should not move when the legs are closer than reset